# Android app crashes when trying to add an imageview in another class

Tags: android, android-imageview

i recently started programming in Android and i came across a little problem. 
What i'm trying to do is:
I have NewsActivity and a NewsRows.class (in the same package). 
So the news activites just creates a new NewsRows object and tells it to fill the TableLayout with new rows.
It works fine as long as i try to add an image from a resource... The app just keeps crashing.
The debugger tells me it can't find the resource but i can't find out why!

My code is here:
News Acitivty

```
package de.myapp.app.activites.news;

import de.myapp.app.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class News extends Activity {
    NewsRows rowClass = new NewsRows();
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.news);

        NewsRows.createNewsEntries(this);
    }

}
```

NewsRows.class

```
package de.myapp.app.activites.news;

import de.myapp.app.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class NewsRows {
static TextView         title;
static TableRow         tRow;
static TableLayout      tLayout;
public NewsRows() {

}

public static void createNewsEntries(Activity contextActivity) {

    ImageView image = new ImageView(contextActivity);
    image.setBackgroundColor(R.drawable.myimage);
    tLayout     = (TableLayout) contextActivity.findViewById(R.id.NewsTable);

    for(int a = 0; a < 100; a++) {
        tRow    = new TableRow(contextActivity);
        title   = new TextView(contextActivity);
        //tRow.addView(image);
        title.setText("This is a test.");
        tRow.addView(title);
        tLayout.addView(tRow);
    }
}

}
```

EDIT:
The line

```
image.setBackgroundColor(R.drawable.myimage);<br />
```

Is actually supposed to be:

```
image.setImageResource(R.drawable.myimage);
```

Comment: Need less to say as soon as i uncomment the tRow.addView part it crashes.

Comment: What exception do you get?  What's in the logcat?  What do you mean "the debugger can't find the resource"?

Comment: It will help if you add the crash log.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to set an image into a background color:
Change this:

```
 image.setBackgroundColor(R.drawable.myimage);
```

to this:

```
 image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.myimage);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't set a drawable for as a background color of your ImageView, that's why you have the resource not found exception on your logcat!!

```
 image.setBackgroundColor(R.drawable.myimage);
```

change it to this:

```
image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.myimage);
```

Also try to change this

```
public static void createNewsEntries(Activity contextActivity)
```

with

```
public static void createNewsEntries(Context contextActivity)
```

Comment: Yeah i just saw that too. Actually that line was auto corrected by eclipse. The original line was:<br />

    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.myimage);

Comment: sorry but i don't think so!!, i have forgot to mention something

Comment: If i change the activity to contect i'm not able to find the TableLayout by Id cause this is an Activity method.

Answer (score 0):

Fun fact:

```
    TableLayout tLayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.NewsTable);
    TableRow tRow = new TableRow(this);
    ImageView image = new ImageView(this);
    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.myimage);
    tRow.addView(image);
    tLayout.addView(tRow);
```

If i put this code right in the News.Activity it works...

Comment: see my updated answer you have to pass context and non an activity object